# Proof for $\gcd$ being the smallest linear combination of $a,b \in \mathbb {Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please vet my approach:

First need prove that for the least positive value combination (let, $l$), it will divide $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Will use the indirect, or contradiction approach to prove that $l \mid a$.  Similar will extend to $l \mid b$.

So, for $l \nmid a, \exists q, r \in \mathbb {Z}$, s.t. $a = al +r, 0 \lt r \lt l$.
Hence, $r = a - q.l = a - q(ax_0 + by_0) = a(1 - qx_0) - qby_0$. So, $r$ is a linear combination of $a, b$ with integer multipliers, let $x,y,$ where $x = 1 - qx_0, y = -qy_0$

The assumed form for $l = ax_0 + by_0$. Given, by contradiction that $0 \lt r \lt l$, have the following inequalities, as the integer multipliers for $r$ must be smaller than of $l$, and positive too:

=> $1- qx_0 \lt x_0$ - (i)  & $-q \lt 1$ - (ii)

=>  $1 \lt x_0(1+q)$ - (i)  & $q \gt -1$ - (ii)

Substituting for $q$ from (ii) into (i), get:

$ 1 \lt x_0($negative value$)$ -- obviously false, hence proved that $l  \mid a$ by contradiction.

---

*Addendum* In view of responses recd., have modified as follows. First, assume that $a,b \gt 0$. Second, form four cases of possible values of the integer multiplier, and will try to prove by contradiction in each.

Case (i) : $x_0 \gt 0, y_0 \gt 0$ : Have already proved this case above.

Case (ii) : $x_0 \gt 0, y_0 \lt 0$ : Implies $-qy_0 \lt y_0$, but as $y_0 \lt 0$, so cancelling $y_0$ from both sides leads to: $-q \gt 1 => q \lt -1$.

The two inequalities are :  $1 \lt x_0(1+q)$ - (i), $q \lt -1$ - (ii)

Substituting for $q$ from (ii) into (i), get: $1 \lt x_0$(negative value),  again obviously false.

Case (iii) : $x_0 \lt 0, y_0 \gt 0$ : Implies the two inequalities are: 
$1- qx_0 \lt x_0$ - (i), $q \gt -1$ - (ii)

$1 \lt x_0(1+q)$, but as $x_0 \lt 0$, so it changes to $-1 \gt x_0(1+q)$, for positive $x_0$. Now, this is also not possible as $(1+q)\gt 0$.

Case (iv) : $x_0 \lt 0, y_0 \lt 0$ : As assume $a, b \gt 0$, so this case is not possible.

Hence, proved for all possible values of $x_0, y_0$.

Comment: Can you please state in your question *what* you want to prove? The mention in the title is not enough, especially as here it is very vague. $\gcd$ is a linear combination ... of what? In which set? Are there any constraints? Looking at your work, it seems that you are trying to prove that, if $l=\gcd(a,b)$ then $l=ax+by$ for some *positive* integers $x,y$, which is not true so cannot be proven. (Take $l=1, a=2, b=3$, for example). If you forget about $x,y$ being positive, drop the second half of your proof (i.e the inequalities) and you will be ok.

Comment: @rtybase I think the solution approach is different, totally different. Most of the answers are not for beginners even.

Comment: @user8734617 Please see my edited OP, particularly in the context of $x,y$ being not positive.

Comment: Just forget any inequalities... You already have the proof in hand where you say "So, $r$ is a linear combination of $a,b$ with integer multipliers, let $x,y$ where $x=1−qx_0$,$y=−qy_0$". Namely, you started with the assumption that $l$ was the smallest positive number with that property and you've concluded that there is a smaller one - $r$, This contradiction proves that it is impossible that $l$ does not divide $a$, hence $l|a$.

Comment: Thanks, so it is a sort of axiom, and anything opposite is false by contradiction.

Comment: Well, sort of... Axioms are just things you assume *in advance* to doing any work within any theory, whereas you can always add *additional* assumptions and see if they hold up or they lead to a contradiction. Here you assumed two things: [1] $l$ is the smallest positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$ and [2] $l$ does not divide $a$. That led you to a contradiction. As [1] must hold at least for *some* $l$ (natural numbers are well ordered - that is a theorem that follows from natural numbers' axioms) then [2] must be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understood from your question: you want to show that if $l = \min\{ ax+by > 0 : x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ then $l \mid a$ and $l \mid b$. Assuming $ l \nmid a$, you write $a = ql + r$ where $ 0 < r < l$, and thereby arrive at $r = a(1-qx_0) + b(-qy_0)$, where $l = ax_0 + by_0$.

Now, you argue that since $0 < r < l$, the integers appearing in the linear combination for $r$ must both be positive, and they must be smaller than the respective integers appearing in the linear combination for $l$. **This is incorrect.** It appears that you are assuming that $x_0$ and $y_0$ are both positive, but this is simply not true. Try computing the linear combinations for positive integers $a$ and $b$, and you will see that $x_0$ and $y_0$ often have opposite sign. It also appears that you are assuming that if one linear combination is smaller than another linear combination, then the same can be said for the respective coefficients. Again, this is not true in general, even if the coefficients are all positive. For example, let $a=1$ and $b=2$. Then $5a+b < 4a+2b$. You can find many more examples yourself by playing around with numbers.

Instead, here is what you need to do to complete the proof. Since $0 < r < l$, and $r$ is expressed as an integral linear combination of $a$ and $b$, it implies that $l$ is not the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. This is a contradiction. Hence, our original hypothesis that $l \nmid a$ is false.

---

Regarding your modified proof, note that you are still making the assumption that if $ax+by < ax’ + by’$, then $x < x’$ and $y < y’$. As I mentioned in the second paragraph above, this is not true in general, regardless of the signs of $x$, $y$, $x’$ and $y’$. So, none of the four cases actually prove the desired result. In fact, since nothing can be said in general about the relative sizes of $x$ and $x’$, and $y$ and $y’$, from the fact that $ax + by < ax’ + by’$, therefore your approach cannot lead to a solution, by my understanding.

The simpler way to conclude the contradiction is as I mentioned in my third paragraph, above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the sort of critical remark that one expects and is highly insightful too.

Comment: Please vet my modified OP. I feel that all sub-cases have been accommodated.

Comment: Thanks, but will take some time to properly assimilate it and respond, if needed.

Comment: I agree, but if such sort of problem occurs elsewhere (i.e., the assumption is not given - on which to easily state by contradiction) and need to just prove by having $4$ inequalities. Also, need take care of the fact that nothing can be said about the relative sizes of $x,y,x',y'$, as stated by you. In that case, need prove for all possible values of these $4$ variables, while keeping true $ax+by \lt ax' + by'$. Then, I just request that what topic of mathematics handles it. If could point exact name of such problem, then would be far better.

Comment: @jiten I don’t know of any particular topic of mathematics that deals with such instances. They occur all over the place, really.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to raise it as a separate question. If I were to do that, then please state the broad terms to state issue correctly, right from the start.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. The study of inequalities is one topic that comes to mind. But I’m really unable to make the question more specific.